# React tailwind + sass build error - resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

Hey guys I have build a react app with tailwind and sass application and when ever i try to run build i get an error:

[image]

This are the files:

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
parser: 'postcss-scss',
plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting')(require('postcss-nesting')),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
        features: { 'nesting-rules': false }
    }),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]
```

};

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nessco-catalog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nesting": "^10.1.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.4",
    "sass": "^1.49.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}\"",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/main.scss -o src/styles/index.scss"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.1",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}
```

Does it even possible to do this allin one file?
where the sass main file is tailwind imports and then my regular sass content using tailwind utils with apply? becuase on npm start it works awesome... only on th build i have problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My fix was to change the configuration:

1. tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
   }
   ```
2. tailwind.config.js

   ```
   module.exports = {
     content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
      theme: {
        colors: {
           transparent: 'transparent',
           black: '#000',
           white: '#fff',
        },
      },
      plugins: [],
   };
   ```
3. postcss.config.js

   ```
   const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
     module.exports = {
        plugins: [
          tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
   };
   ```
4. package.json

   ```
   {
       "name": "react-typescript-webpack",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "main": "index.js",
       "scripts": {
           "dev": "webpack serve --mode development --progress --hot --config ./webpack.config.development.js",
           "build": "webpack --mode production --config ./webpack.config.production.js"
       },
       "keywords": [
           "react",
           "typescript",
           "webpack",
           "scss"
       ],
       "dependencies": {
           "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
           "i18next": "^21.9.2",
           "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0",
           "react": "^18.2.0",
           "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
           "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
           "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
           "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
       },
       "devDependencies": {
           "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
           "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
           "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
           "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
           "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
           "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
           "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
           "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
           "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
           "postcss": "^8.4.14",
           "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
           "postcss-preset-env": "^7.7.2",
           "sass": "^1.53.0",
           "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
           "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
           "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
           "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
           "typescript": "^4.7.4",
           "webpack": "^5.73.0",
           "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
           "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
       }
   }
   ```
5. app.scss

   ```
   .row-square {
       .square {
           @apply flex h-[60px] w-[60px] md:h-[80px] md:w-[80px] items-center justify-center bg-[#ffffff] active:scale-125 transition duration-200 ease-in hover:bg-[#ffffff];

           button {
               @apply h-[60px] w-[60px] md:h-[80px] md:w-[80px] border;
           }

           .player-1 {
               @apply bg-blue-100;
           }

           .player-2 {
               @apply bg-yellow-100;
           }

           .player-3 {
               @apply bg-green-100;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to a feature that your are using from tailwind that isn't being parsed properly via the `resolve-url-loader` package.

## Solution A - Quick & Dirty

Add a dummy placeholder CSS property `foo:bar;` wherever you are using custom variables in custom tailwind classes. [Read more here.](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/8806)

```
.dashboardCards {
    @apply bg-[#fff] hover:bg-[#d8fffe];
}
```

to

```
.dashboardCards {
    @apply bg-[#fff] hover:bg-[#d8fffe];
    foo: bar;
}
```

## Solution B

In our project, the following was causing trouble in the `.sass` files - using custom colour variables.

```
  .menuItemContainer {
    @apply border-[#242424]  text-[#a4a6b3]; 
    @apply hover:border-[#5bbfbd] hover:bg-[#2e2e2e] hover:text-[#5bbfbd]
  }
```

So we changed it to standard sass/css way of writing styles.

```
.menuItemContainer {
    border-color: #242424;
    color: #a4a6b3;

    &:hover {
      border-color: #5bbfbd;
      color: #5bbfbd;
      background: #2e2e2e;
    }
  }
```

& voila build is fixed for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but I think I fixed it. Please check if you have rgb values in tailwind.config.js. if so, please change them into hex values. From my experience tailwind has some troubles with rgb values. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).